# What is the best way in different screen sizes {Screen width - Screen Height - Smallest Screen width}

Tags: java, android

I want to Know The best way  in different screen sizes {Screen width or Screen Height or Smallest Screen width}  ;
And the values {360w - ... - 720w}that I use to get a design that matches all phones.
ThankYou

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes read this.. you can create seperate layouts for tablets, most tablets would come under devices having more than 600 dp of width.. most phones would come under devices less than 600 dp..